# Setup a process to update field based on multiple values

Tags: visual-workflow, formula-field, configuration, administrator

Currently, I'm trying to set up a process to calculate Routing Region based on the country field. For example:- if the country equals any of the below values it needs to be tagged as 'Latam'. And we need to set up these fields for other objects in the future.

Bahamas,Barbados,Dominican Republic,dominican republic,Haiti,haiti,Jamaica,jamaica,bahamas,etc.

I feel the formula field approach will be challenging to manage in the future because if we will expand regions in near future. I need suggestions to set up this process through the configuration

Answer (score 0):

A good process for this may be to use Custom Metadata.

Meta Object: RoutingRegion__mdt

Meta Record API Names: The regions you have listed such as "Bahamas"

Meta Field: Routing Region (i.e "Latam")

You can then use a flow or a formula field to get the desired field/Routing Region with the `getInstance(developerName)` method.